# Showing time dynamically but with three seconds difference

Tags: android, datetime, xamarin, time

I saw this link [Android Scheduled Timer - Mono for Android or Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342662/android-scheduled-timer-mono-for-android-or-java)

I used this code but the output has three seconds difference. My system time is 3:56:33 but my program output is 3:56:30.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

namespace App21
{
    [Activity(Label = "App21", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        TextView tv1;
        TextView tv2;
        TextView tv3;
        System.Timers.Timer t;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            tv1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            tv2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            tv3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            t = new System.Timers.Timer();
            t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimeEvent);
            t.Interval = 1000;
            t.Enabled = true;
            t.Start();
        }
        private void OnTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(delegate
            {
                tv1.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
                tv2.Text = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
                tv3.Text = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code on a Virtual Device and I have only 1 second delay (I think because you set Interval = 1000). 3 seconds is very strange.

Comment: But I see 3 seconds. How do I set Interval?

Comment: t.Interval = 100;

Comment: with t.Interval = 100 I also see 3 seconds.

Comment: I don't know. Post your Project on github so we can take a look

Comment: The entire program is this. I do not know why it has such an output. I am confused

Comment: There is another way for getting correct seconds and minutes and hours?

Comment: Have you checked the system time of your emulator/device? `DateTime.Now` shows the current time of your emulator or device. And please try it on other emulator/device to check whether the problem persists.

Comment: OK. My emulator has 3 seconds difference with time of my computer.